# Trying to get the timing on a JQuery animation correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-animate, fadein

Working on an existing Rails app and not very familiar with JQuery. Right now trying to modify the timing on the different fades so that they come in sequentially as opposed to all at once. Even after extensive reconfiguration of the delays, the window Timeouts, etc. I've been unable to see any perceptible change in timing. Can anyone help? Here is the original code.

Thanks!

```
- content_for :scripts do
    = javascript_include_tag 'jquery.easing.1.3', 'jquery.slides'

:javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#splash-video').on('ended', function() {
            $('#splash').hide();
            //window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('#post-splash').show();
            //},500);
            $('#slides').slides({
                play: 8000,
                pause: 5000,
                hoverPuase: true,
                paginationClass: 'slides-pagination',
                effect: 'fade',
                fadeSpeed: 1200,
                fadeEasing: 'easeOutQuad',
                /*animationStart: function(current) {
                    //$('#slide-caption-' + (current+1)).fadeIn(2500);
                    console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                },
                animationComplete: function(current) {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#slide-caption-' + (current+1)).fadeIn(4000);
                        $('#slide-caption-' + (current)).fadeOut(1200);
                    },6800);
                }*/
            });
        });
        /*window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#splash').hide();
        },4500);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#post-splash').show();
        },5500);*/
        //$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({ alwaysShowControls: false });

        //$('.container.front-end h1').html($('.container.front-end h1').html().replace('&amp;', '<div class="h1-specialchar">&amp;</div>'));
        /*$('#fade1').delay(700).fadeTo(700, 1, function () {
            $('#fade2').fadeTo(700, 1, function () {
                $('#fade3').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInRight');
            });
        });*/
        //$("#fade2 p").each(function() {
        //   $(this).addClass('animated transparent');
        //});

        $("#fade2 p").addClass("animated");
        $('#fade1').delay(700).fadeTo(700, 1);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#fade2 p").each(function(index) {
                $(this).delay(150*index).fadeTo(0, 1, function() {
                    $(this).addClass("fadeInDownFaster");
                });
            });
        },800);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#slides').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInRight');
        },1800);
    });
```

Does this seem a little closer?

Thank you for the answer. Does this seem correct? Getting there at least?

```
$("#fade2 p").addClass("animated");'
        window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('#fade1').delay(200).fadeTo(500, 1, function() {
                    $("#fade2 p").each(function(index) {
                    $(this).delay(150*index).fadeTo(400, 1, function() {
                        $(this).addClass("fadeInDownFaster");
            });
        },800);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#slides').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInRight');
        },1800);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the fade to the callback of fadeto it will execute after check this example http://jsfiddle.net/5NPDD/

```
$('#fade1').fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
    $('#fade2').fadeTo(500, 0, function() {

    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Modified the code slightly. Any thoughts?